# Interchanging one finite sum and one infinite sum

Tags: calculus

Imagine we have a non-conditionally convergent series of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f\left(n,\ k\right)}{\left(n-k\right)!}$$
Clearly, for $k>n$ all the summands are 0. In other words, the series above is equal to the series below
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(n,\ k\right)}{\left(n-k\right)!}$$

My question is, under what conditions could these two series be interchanged? Clearly we cannot use Fubini's theorem as the series is not conditionally convergent.

My first thought was to just interchange them, as although both sums run from 1 to infinity the second sum is in actual fact finite. However I am not sure how to rigorously justify that. Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(n,\ k\right)}{\left(n-k\right)!}$ is not equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f\left(n,\ k\right)}{\left(n-k\right)!}$. In fact, the first one is not even defined.

Comment: This is a typical problem you will also have when you apply the Fubini theorem to $\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^x ...\,dy\,dx$. Just draw a picture what shape the $(x,y)$-region of integration has and then flip the order of integration. Same principle applies you the double sum.